# Generate multiple API keys through powershell in AWS

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I want to create API keys to my REST API in AWS programmatically through a script.

```
response = client.create_api_key(
  name='string',
  description='string',
  enabled=True|False,
  generateDistinctId=True|False,
  value='string',
  stageKeys=[
      {
          'restApiId': 'string',
          'stageName': 'string'
      },
  ],
  customerId='string'
)
```

I found this method and am hoping the script should look something like this. Does anyone know how i successfully create the API keys?

To do this using CLI I used this and it works fine:

```
 aws apigateway create-api-key --name 'WH1-In4m-ApiKey' --description 'development.' --enabled --stage-keys restApiId='yz50sp19a7',stageName='wh1'
```

How to replicate in powershell for aws?

Comment: That is a python API. Use Boto3 to write a simple script to generate an API key on demand.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your AWS credentials correctly configured, you can use:

1. AWS CLI in your script (provided you have AWS CLI installed) to generate an API key: [create-api-key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/create-api-key.html)
2. Use Python Boto3 library: [create-api-key](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.create_api_key)

You may have to install [AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) for option #1

Comment: I used aws apigateway create-api-key --name 'Dev API Key' --description 'Used for development' --enabled --stage-keys restApiId='a1b2c3d4e5',stageName='dev'

If I run this command from Windows Powershell for aws.. I am getting the error that aws is not recognized as an internal  or external cmdlet

Comment: This happens form inside windows powershell for aws. What is the solution to this.
I basically want to run this command and have followed the steps to configure aws.

Comment: I have windows powershell for aws installed

Comment: @the_coder_in_me add aws cli to your PATH. If you don't know how, just google it or http://edsellandicho.com/tutorials/index.php/blog/85-solution-to-aws-cli-command-line-interface-on-windows-64-bit-not-working-after-installation

Comment: aws apigateway create-api-key --name 'WH1-In4m-ApiKey' --description 'development.' --enabled --stage-keys restApiId='yz50sp19a7',stageName='wh1'

This works in aws cli but can it be done from windows powershell for aws...

Comment: Following the MSI Installer instructions here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html, then opening powershell lets me use the aws cli. You may need to add it to your path as previous comments have said.